# OpenCV test failed in Yocto-Jethro

Tags: opencv, yocto

I have added [meta-openembedded](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/jethro) recipes in the Yocto project, at Jethro branch OpenCV version is 2.4.
After building while testing the sample applications provided by opencv-samples_2.4.bb gives these samples :

```
adaptiveskindetector  contours         facedetect  find_obj_calonder  morphology   mushroom          pyramid_segmentation
bgfg_codebook         convert_cascade  fback_c     find_obj_ferns     motempl      one_way_sample    smiledetect
blobtrack_sample      delaunay         find_obj    latentsvmdetect    mser_sample  polar_transforms  tree_engine
```

but while testing I got this error :

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
>   Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
>   are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
>   re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file
>   /home/ymj/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 516

I have added in local.conf:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " opencv opencv-samples python-opencv"
```

Is anything more needed to get full-fledged opencv operations.

Comment: It could be you need numpy when using python.  Take a look at the most recent version of the recipe (http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/opencv/opencv_4.3.0.bb?h=master) for inspiration.

Comment: Are you using X11? If yes, then you need to install gtk

Comment: @CleitonBueno No, X11 failed to build. I'm using weston DISTRO with qt5 support. Also what is the right way of adding gtk , since I'm always getting this error : stackoverflow.com/questions/28776053/opencv-gtk2-x-error.. only gtk+3 works, but sample application depends on gtk+.

Comment: @vermaete Yes, python-numpy is added as : RDEPENDS_python-opencv = "python-core python-numpy" in the opencv_2.4.bb, looks like IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " opencv opencv-samples" isnt providing all the binaries into file system